# MKMap cannot set the region in the ViewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to set the coordinates and region for a MKmap. The code that I have written work if I put it in the viewDidAppear however I do not want it to be in this method as I do not want it to be set every time the view appears.

This is the code that im trying to implement in these methods

```
//set the map delegate
MapView.delegate = (id)self;

//set the co-ords
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = LAT_POSN;
zoomLocation.longitude= LON_POSN;

//create region
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, startZoom, startZoom);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [MapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[MapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

EDIT: startZoom is a constant and I have logged it to make sure it there before setting the region

I have tried using

```
if (self.isMovingToParentViewController )
```

To get this to run the first time the view is called but it still shows the same result.

This is what it should look like.

[image: should look like]

But this is what im getting.

[image: bad image]

Does anyone know why this might be? 
Thanks

Answer: 
I used tkanzakic answer To make sure that some of my code was only used once. 
Also the reason that the region wasnt being set was that it didnt like this line of code.

```
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [MapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
```

Comment: What about `viewDidLoad` ? Have you tried including your code in this method?

Comment: Yes I have tried the DidLoad, WillAppear and DidAppear. The only one that worked was the DidAppear

Comment: At the moment you implement the code described, you already have a value set for the variable `startZoom`? Check it with a breakpoint. Maybe the value is `nil`, not setting the region correctly.

Comment: What about zoomLocation - is that correctly initialised?

Comment: Yeah If you look at the two images the are centred at the same point but the region show is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in calling `-[MKMapView regionThatFits:]`.

When you set the region for a map view, the view usually has to adjust your region a little to make it fit correctly within its bounds. Usually the aspect ratio of the region you specified doesn't match the aspect ratio of the actual view, for example.

**If** you *really* need to know the adjusted region before you set it, you can use `-[MKMapView regionThatFits:]`. The problem with doing that too early (e.g, in `viewDidLoad`) is that the map view calculates the "region that fits" according to it's own size on screen. That size may not be correct or isn't meaningful, in the case of autolayout, until the actual layout happens. So when viewDidLoad is called, the map view probably doesn't know its correct actual size yet.

From your code, it doesn't seem like you hold onto the adjustedRegion for very long, other than to just pass it right back to the map view. So you can omit that and just do this instead:

`[mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:NO];`

Then the mapview will adjust that region, as needed. Later if you need to know what the adjusted region is, you can ask the map view for that later (in viewDidAppear: or some other time after the layout has happened).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this code do not works in the `viewDidLoad` method, but to avoid that your code get fired every time the view appears you can include a static variable (or an attribute or a property if you don't want to use a static variable), like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    static BOOL isFirstLoad = YES;
    if (isFirstLoad) {
        // Put your code here
        isFirstLoad = NO;
    }

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

this will guaranteed that your code only run once.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I kind of wanted to find out why this happening as im sure I will come across it again. If I cant find out why I will use this method. Thanks.

Comment: With property isMovingToParentViewController introduced in ios 5.0 in view controller class, you don't have to take such Boolean variable.

Comment: @Silly thanks for the tip, I haven't here about this property before.

Comment: @Will is the variable `startZoom` defined in the `viewDidLoad`, can you NSLog for it and check it has the correct value assigned?

Comment: Yes It is defined and I have tested it in the log. I will edit the question